# CNAME with S3 buckets

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cname-record

I have a Web and I wanted to move its images to AWS S3. Say it's called `mypage.com` and I can access to an image like this:

```
https://mypage.com/pics/one.jpg
```

I created a bucket called `static.mypage.com` to put there all the images, so now I can access to the images like this:

```
https://static.mypage.com.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pics/one.jpg
```

As it is a very long name, I want use a "shortener" using DNS.

So, I'd want to know how to set the CNAME in my DNS provider to make possible that if I go to...

```
https://static.mypage.com/pics/one.jpg
```

...I'd get the images from the bucket.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not sufficient just to have the CNAME: the web server also needs to be aware of your subdomain. Also, we can't tell how to add CNAME records  at an unknown provider with an unknown configuration interface.

Comment: I just want to map every access to static.mypage.com to static.mypage.com.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work as you think. A CNAME merely tells that the hostname can be found on the same IP address, but it doesn't make the necessary application layer modifications to the HTTP request (`Host` header).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the past S3 supported **FQDN bucket names** - i.e. exactly what you needed. Where FQDN = Fully Qualified Domain Name, i.e. full host name like *static.mypage.com*. The problem is that this only works with HTTP and not with HTTPS because there is no way to make S3 use a SSL certificate with your bucket name / host name (*static.mypage.com*).

You can still do it if you're happy with HTTP-only traffic. Simply create a `static.mypage.com` CNAME at your registrar pointing to `s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. S3 will recognise the `Host:` header in the request and look into the right S3 bucket. Provided that the objects in the bucket are publicly accessible the URL ***http**://static.mypage.com/pics/one.jpg* should work just fine.

However as soon as you access the same over HTTPS you will get a SSL Certificate Validation error because the hostname in the S3 certificate **.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com* won't match the expected *static.mysite.com*.

The **solution is CloudFront** which can sit in front of your S3 and handle the right SSL certificate for it:

1. create a free SSL certificate for *static.mysite.com* in *[Amazon Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)* (or upload your 3rd party issued SSL cert to ACM).
2. set up a *[CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)*, attach the SSL cert to it
3. configure the CloudFront distribution to use your S3 bucket as the *Origin*
4. configure a *static.mysite.com* CNAME at your DNS provider to point to the CF distribution name, e.g. *d123456abcdef.cloudfront.net*
5. with that your desired URL ***https**://static.mypage.com/pics/one.jpg* should finally work.

Also have a look at [Routing traffic to a website that is hosted in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very well explained and detailed solution :)

Comment: Also cloudFront is a CDN meant exactly for your use case it improve serving and caching static content at edges locations.

Comment: CloudFront will also reduce your costs in most cases, because serving bytes out of CloudFront costs a lot less than transferring bytes out of S3 (though on a cache miss you will pay both of those costs).

Comment: I don't think you pay for traffic from S3 to CloudFront edge locations any more @Riking . I'm not 100% sure but I think I read that a while back.

Comment: Allowing CloudFlare to proxy your S3 assets will also resolve the HTTPS problem at a dramatically lower cost than CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

Logon to your web host control panel and select “Manage DNS Server Settings” or similar
Create a new CNAME entry for your domain. For your example of static.mypage.com, the entry is:

```
Name: static
Type: CNAME
Value: s3-external-3.amazonaws.com.
```

(If you are an American user, use  s3.amazonaws.com. instead)
And yes, the dot at the end of “s3-external-3.amazonaws.com.” is correct, for my web host. Look at your other entries to figure out what your should enter for your web host.

See here for more info
https://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternate solution that avoids DNS CNAME and CloudFront costs: make it all inside the NGINX server.
It's a great solution, optimized with proxy cache.
Here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639182/nginx-proxy-amazon-s3-resources/44749584
Hope this helps as it helped me! :)

Comment: CloudFront is a CDN with servers all over the world. Comparing that to going through a single server which may be on the other side of the world for some users is a bit weird.

Comment: With big projects, yes, but with a small project it's enough for me

Comment: Nginx is the single point of failure though. All the other solutions are fully *Redundant*, *Highly Available* and support *parallel throughput*. If you go down the Nginx path you can just as well store the files there and not bother with S3 at all.